# from commandline howto call userdefined functions in shell script

Tags: shell

Unix shell script:

I have 7 functions those need to be executed as command line inputs, I tried with below code it’s not executing function.

```
if [ "$VAL" == "1" ]
then
fun1
elif [ "$VAL" == "2" ]
then
fun2
elif [ "$VAL" == "3" ]
then
fun3
elif [ "$VAL" == "4"]
then
fun4
elif [ "$$VAL" ==" 5" ]
then
fun5
elif [ "$VAL" == "6" ]
then
fun6
elif [ "$VAL" == "7" ] then
fun7
else
echo -e "Invalid input.............\n"
Help
  exit
fi
```

Output:

```
Usage:  ./script  $VAL
#   ./script  2
Invalid input...........
```

Comment: The example usage `./script 2` doesn't show 2 being assigned to the VAL. Why not change all of the if/elif s to `if [ "$1" == "6" ] ; then`. Else learn to use the shell debugging options `set -vx` to see how your code is being executed and what values have been substituted for your variables. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Being honest I don't see any bug in your code (besides `$$VAL` when comparing to 5). Are you sure that `VAL` is equal 2? Maybe try to call your code in this way `./script 2` instead of `./script $VAL`. What is more I would recommend to use `case` statement:

```
 case "$VAL" in
 "1")
    fun1
    ;;
 "2")
    fun2
    ;;
 "3")
    fun3
    ;;
 *)
    echo -e "Invalid input.............\n" 
    ;;
 esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is a code for functions in linux, hope this helps

```
func() 
{
if [ thisconditionistrue ]
then
a=100
else
a=500
fi
}

#CallerScript
a=50
passme=Thisisvalue
func $passme
```